# Header not 100% in width when zoomed in

Tags: html, css

This is kind of weird, and I don't know how to explain this much here. When you zoom in to my website and scroll to the right, the header part + title box is missing. This does not happen when it is zoomed out. Previously, I set the body-width to 1024px and when I zoom out the entire page zooms out to the left (which is not desired if someone has a higher screen resolution) and I prefer it to remain centered. So, I let the body fill the full width but this does not appear to do so for the top part. Not sure what is causing it.

```
header {
   width: 100%;    

body {
   width: 100%;
}
```

See my website [here](http://lionsxii360.com/fixtures-results/) and you will be able to understand.

JS fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/D22Jd/
Zoom in and scroll to the right to see what I meant

Comment: mmmm...`url`s not recommended....possible to give jsfiddle??? :)

Comment: @NoobEditor I managed to squeeze in the info, and yup, when zoomed in, the above error takes place so here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D22Jd/

Comment: well, my best guess is that the scroll appears because you have set ` width: 960px;` in `container`.....Remove it and it seems to work fine!! => http://jsfiddle.net/D22Jd/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/HhzyQ/1/

Comment: Thank you very much, but Surjith provided an answer so I have accepted that already. Thanks all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the below code to CSS will fix your issue.

```
html, body {
min-width: 1024px; /*adjust as per your need*/
}
```